# How can I get the c++20 std lib?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, c++20

How do I get sys_seconds? I use /usr/bin/c++ on Ubuntu 20.04 to compile following snippet:

```
RCLCPP_WARN_STREAM(get_logger(), "Time: " << std::chrono::sys_seconds(time_.seconds()));
```

and I get following error: error: ‘sys_seconds’ is not a member of ‘std::chrono’;

c++ output is:

```
c++ (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0
```

According to: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/system_clock c++20 should have a namespace sys_seconds, according to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support c++9 supports c++20. But when I check the file /usr/include/c++/9/chrono I see only the c++11 version. I make sure that I'm compiling with c++20 by setting following line in my CMakeLists.txt

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
```

How can I get the missing c++20 std lib?

Comment: There's a preview of C++20 chrono here: https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date

Comment: I tried to get that to work, but failed. I don't remember anymore why, but I found another solution now. It's crazy what legends answer on SO ;)

Comment: If you want help with getting it to work, just let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> according to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support c++9 supports c++20

That's not what the linked page says. On your system, c++ is linked to g++ by default. The linked page says that **some** C++20 features are implemented in GCC 9, while many features are not.

> How can I get the missing c++20 std lib?

By installing a language implementation that has implemented that library.

Comment: Ok, right. This seems like a weird concept to me to only support a part of the new standard. Usually things I encounter support something or they dont. I didnt know that compilers only support subsets of a new standard sometimes.

Comment: @Hakaishin C++ standard changes are massive, and it makes little sense to delay all features until everything is done. This is called "experimental" support for the new standard.